# How to design and distribute libraries with rich UI, interactions and dependencies in Android?

Tags: android, android-library, android-jetpack, software-distribution

I'm writing a SDK (Android aar library) that will be used by many apps. The idea is to provide an Activity to the client app to handle a complexe flow of steps. The SDK is built like many other Android apps: multiple screens, a dedicated theme, navigation, HTTPS communication with an API, etc.

I've been using Jetpack (and other 3rd party libraries) for a while now and it seems natural to me to use what Google recommend nowadays.

If I use AndroidX, Navigation Component, Retrofit, Dagger etc, will I have trouble distributing my library? Will I run into compatibility issues, version mismatchs and other unwanted side effects?

*I suppose I could use low level Android APIs and go back to Loaders, HttpPost and FragmentManager to minimize friction but that's far from ideal.*

Answer (score 0):

I am quite new to this as well.
At work, I have started making a lot of my code in to Android Libraries and using Sonatype Nexus as a repo.

I believe something like [compile only dependencies](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies) is the way to avoid a lot of dependency clash issues?

> Dependencies whose API is required at compile time but whose implementation is to be provided by a consuming library, application or runtime environment.